# Game center facebook like

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

So today i started developing with the new iOS 6 SDK and noticed that my game has a new Facebook Like button in Game Center(which is greyed out because i didn't specify anything on it yet). So my question is, how can i put a link of a facebook page behind that "Like" button?

My iPhone game has a facebook page already btw.

Thanks already,

Comment: hmmm just a hunch, haven't seen the new GC yet. If this is a like button everyone could see, you probably have to enter your FB credentials in iOS 6 first. You can do that in the Settings app, under … Facebook

Answer (score 8):

Hope it is not too late. Just watched one of WWDC videos and they said, if someone will click the like button, it'll means that person like the game and link to itunes will be generated (i guess also posted on your wall). it is not for liking your app page.

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering the same thing.   I have scoured the apple documentation and iTunesconnect site with no information.

EDIT: It appears that the button was disabled because the app isn't released yet.  I have checked my other games (which are released), and the new Game Center Like button works.  I didn't have to do anything to the code or itunesconnect to get this to work.

Comment: Even if it was released, how can it still know which FB page to like if you didn't specify anything?

Comment: @VellumInteractive What happens you tap like for your games that work?