# How to enable Facebook like button in game center for iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, game-center, leaderboard

I'm making an App which supports game center. Within the leaderboard page there's a facebook like button. However it's disabled. Will it be enabled when it's for sale in the Appstore or do I need to do additional configurations in code?

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as such?

Comment: Hi @KaanDedeoglu, what do you mean by it will be enabled? The player will "like" which facebook page? Do we need to hard code our game facebook url? Or do we need to set something in itunes connect? Edited: Opps got my answer here. hope it helps. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521245/game-center-facebook-like

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will be enabled in the production version of the app, only if the user has installed and enabled Facebook integration within iOS 6. Otherwise, it will say, *Facebook Liking Unavailable*.